# Проверка вводимых данных в коде

Tags: python, python-3.x, исключения

Сделал код, который генерирует случайным образом матрицу и складывает ее построчно. Еще хотел сделать проверку чтобы в размер матрицы можно было вводить только числа и при вводе других символов выдавало сообщение о неверно вводимых данных.
В итоге перепробовал все и гуглить пытался, так ничего и не получатся.

```
import random

n = int(input("Введите размер матрицы: "))
m = int(input("Введите размер матрицы: "))  
matrix = [[random.randint(1, 10) for _ in range(m)] for _ in range(n)]

print("Матрица:")
for row in matrix:
    print(row)

sums = [sum(row) for row in matrix]

print("Суммы по строкам:")
for row_sum in sums:
    print(row_sum)
```

Comment: Попробуйте через цикл:
while True:
      ваши операторы по присвоению m и n
      break
except ValueError:
      m = 
      n  = с повторным запросом ввода размера. например

Comment: @Volk, по вашим правкам, почитайте вот это: [Что-такое мета-метки?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1160/1365). Большинство меток, которые вы добавляете (типа "числа", "обучение" и другие, "математика" тоже на грани) - это метаметки, их добавлять не нужно. Наоборот лучше удалять, если встречаются. Практически в каждом вопросе есть числа, строки, математика в том или ином виде, но это не значит, что на все вопросы нужно навешивать эти метки.

Comment: Ок, почитаю. Пока ещё не читал, но я добавляю исходя из логики, если вопрос касается именно чисел и человек не может разобраться и касается математики. Так, я с вами согласен, что везде можно тогда ставить, но ставлю не везде.

Comment: @Volk "не везде" метаметки тоже не нужно ставить. Метка "математика" в принципе больше нужна только для вопросов по математике, а не по программированию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант.

Блок `try` позволяет проверить блок кода на наличие ошибок. 
Блок `except` позволяет обработать ошибку.

```
import random

flag = True
while flag:
    try:
        n = int(input("Введите количкство строк матрицы   : "))
        m = int(input("Введите количкство столбцов матрицы: ")) 
        flag = False
    except:
        print('\nНеверно задан размкр матрицы. Попробуйте еще раз.\n')
 
matrix = [[random.randint(1, 10) for _ in range(m)] for _ in range(n)]

print(f"\nМатрица: {n}х{m}")
#for row in matrix:
#    print(row)
print(*matrix, sep='\n')

sums = [sum(row) for row in matrix]

print("\nСуммы по строкам:")
for i, row_sum in enumerate(sums):
    print(f'Суммы по строке {i+1}: {row_sum}')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_i(msg, s=''):
    i = input(f'{s}\n{msg}')
    return int(i) if i.isdigit() else get_i(msg, s='Неверно задан размер матрицы. Попробуйте еще раз.')

n, m = map(get_i, ["Введите количество строк матрицы: ", "Введите количество столбцов матрицы: "])
print(n, m)
```